# WARNING - "Undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]"

Tags: c

I am trying to send my string of characters through UART using C programming language. I do it by loading my characters into THR register one by one like this:

```
unsigned char posiljka[] = "Ziga Lausegger";    

while(1){

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < ( sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0]) ) ; ++i ){
        THR = posiljka[i];
    }
```

This compiles and works completely fine. When I change `<` in the for statement to `<=` my program looks like this:

```
unsigned char posiljka[] = "Ziga Lausegger";    

while(1){

    for ( int i = 0 ; i <= ( sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0]) ) ; ++i ){
        THR = posiljka[i];
    }
```

and produces a warning during compilation:

```
/home/ziga/Dropbox/workspace/mikrokrmilniki/LPC4088/primeri/delujoci/010-uart> make -j2
compiling main.c (gcc)
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:48:18: warning: iteration 15u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
    THR = posiljka[i];
                  ^
main.c:42:3: note: containing loop
   for ( int i = 0 ; i <= ( sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0]) ) ; ++i ){
   ^
linking executable.elf (gcc)

*****
***** You must modify vector checksum value in *.bin and *.hex files.
*****

arm-none-eabi-size executable.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  26496     188     464   27148    6a0c executable.elf
*** Finished ***
```

The program works, but I still want to know what does this warning mean?

Comment: It is telling you that you are invoking undefined behaviour - this is because you are reading beyond the limits of your array

Comment: You know arrays are zero-indexed? `0` to `14` are valid indexes.

Comment: Jesus. I forgot the basics... It starts with 0!!! =) Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last element of your array is at index `sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0]) - 1`. If you change `<` with `<=`, the last iteration of your loop with try to access:

```
 THR = posiljka[sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0])];
```

that is one past the last element of your array. Accessing an element outside of an array invokes undefined behavior and the compiler is kind to tell you.

> The program works

No, it does not. You program is erroneous and it can crash in a further execution or if compiled with a different compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In the second case, code accessed `posiljka[sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0])]` which is outside the array bounds.

In this case, `sizeof(posiljka)/sizeof(posiljka[0])` is `15`, so `posiljka[15]` is one pass the array element containing the null character.

That code "works" is undefined behavior.

---

An interesting aspect of undefined behavior is that a compiler, when it is using "aggressive-loop-optimizations", can sometimes detect this out array access.  Since it is UB, the compiler could skip attempting `posiljka[15]` (Or it might not on Tuesdays.), thus doing the loop in 1 less iterations than directed.